# How do I detect the format of a file LOCALLY on the command line?

Tags: windows, command-line, file-format, utility

I do not want to upload my private files anywhere.

I do not have any use of anything which guesses the format based on the file extension.

I'm trying to find some sort of utility which is able to let me do something like this:

```
detect_file_type.exe "C:\tmp\weirdfile.xyz"
```

And then output:

```
SQLite Database file
```

I hope I'm clear enough. I often want to know the format of some weird binary format, but the file extension (if any such exists at all!) is never useful, often very ambiguous, and it's impossible for me to upload my private data anywhere for some website to figure it out. It must be a local tool which runs exclusively on my computer and does not make any external requests.

Is there such a (free) thing? Some open source project, I imagine.

Comment: This question looks like it has several options: https://superuser.com/questions/272338/what-is-the-equivalent-to-the-linux-file-command-for-windows

Comment: TrID https://mark0.net/soft-trid-e.html